# Reference to an enclosing class method cannot be extracted. Code: -32011 . Flutter error while extract widget Form

Tags: flutter, dart

Unable to extract widget Form. It gives
[Error - 1:02:18 pm] Request workspace/executeCommand failed.
Message: Reference to an enclosing class method cannot be extracted.
Code: -32011

```
Column(enter code here
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              height: 350,
              child: isAccountClicked != true
                  ? Container(
                    child: Form(
                        key: _globalKey,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                controller: _emailTextController,
                                decoration: BuildInputFieldDecoration(
                                    'Enter email', 'example@email.com'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                  )
                  : Text(''),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Automatic extraction of widget didn't work, Doing it manually worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30314199)

Comment: Sure thing @S.M.JAHANGIR